# How can Nginx serve index.html while proxying POST requests using React Router's HistoryLocation

Tags: html, http, nginx, reactjs, react-router

I cannot figure out how to have nginx to serve my static files with React Router's HistoryLocation configuration. The setups I've tried either prevent me from refreshing or accessing the url as a top location (with a 404 Cannot GET /...) or prevent me from submitting POST requests.

Here's my initial nginx setup (not including my mime.types file):

**nginx.conf**

```
# The maximum number of connections for Nginx is calculated by:
# max_clients = worker_processes * worker_connections
worker_processes auto;

# Process needs to run in foreground within container    
daemon off;

events {
  worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
  # Hide nginx version information.
  server_tokens off;

  # Define the MIME types for files.
  include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;

  # Update charset_types due to updated mime.types
  charset_types
    text/xml
    text/plain 
    text/vnd.wap.wml
    application/x-javascript
    application/rss+xml
    text/css
    application/javascript
    application/json;

  # Speed up file transfers by using sendfile() to copy directly
  # between descriptors rather than using read()/write().
  sendfile      on;

  # Define upstream servers
  upstream node-app {
    ip_hash;
    server 192.168.59.103:8000;
  }

  include sites-enabled/*;
}
```

**default**

```
server {
  listen  80;
  root    /var/www/dist;
  index   index.html index.htm;

  location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
    expires 1d;
  }

  location @proxy {
    proxy_set_header    Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header    Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_set_header    Host $host;
    proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header    X-NginX-Proxy true;

    proxy_http_version  1.1;
    proxy_redirect      off;
    proxy_pass          http://node-app;
    proxy_cache_bypass  $http_upgrade;
  }

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @proxy;
  }

}
```

All the functionality I'm expecting of nginx as a reverse proxy is there, except it gives me the aforementioned 404 Cannot GET. After poking around for solutions, I tried to add

```
if (!-e $request_filename){
  rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.html break;
}
```

in the `location /` block. This allows me to refresh and directly access the routes as top locations, but now I can't submit PUT/POST requests, instead getting back a 405 method not allowed. I can see the requests are not being handled properly as the configuration I added now rewrites all my requests to /index.html, and that's where my API is receiving all the requests, but I don't know how to accomplish both being able to submit my PUT/POST requests to the right resource, as well as being able to refresh and access my routes using React Router's HistoryLocation.